# Object sender to control sender?

Tags: c#, object, sender

Is there a way for me to change object sender into, say, control sender? What I want in the end is for object sender to tell me the controller count (controller 15, for instance), rather then it tell me "system.project.label, text : 'text here'".

I do have a way around this issue by looking through each controller on a sheet and matching object sender to said controller, but that is a fairly lengthy workaround. I'm curious if anyone knows a way to get sender to report it's control location instead.

Comment: What are "object sender" and "control sender"? I have never heard these terms in regards to c#.

Comment: @Oded I think he's talking about the first parameter of an event handler delegate.

Comment: This is events in a windows forms - I assume.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, cant get your question.

Comment: @Brian, @Alistad - On reflection, I believe you are right. Very badly worded.

Comment: @Charles, you maybe forgot that there are other people reading your question. So please, provide some context.

Comment: This is a very poorly worded question, but it may be due to the asker not yet having the vocabulary to describe the problem. Very common with beginning developers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the `object sender` argument of an event handler, then you can always cast it to a control.

```
if(sender is Control)
{
   var myControl = sender as Control;
}
```